# WHERE Only on Existing Row Results Above

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to return results from a query where the `WHERE` takes account of values returned in the rows above the current row.

In my example query below, if a value from TableC.Colb has already been returned in the previous rows of the main `SELECT`, I want to exclude it from the `OUTER APPLY` and move onto the next row where `ColA > Col1`

```
Select TableA.Col1, TableA.Col2, TableC.Colb

From
(Select x.Col1, X.Col2  From (values(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D'), (5, 'E'), (6, 'F')) as X(Col1, Col2)) as TableA


Outer Apply
(Select min(TableB.Colb) as Colb
From (Select x.ColA, X.ColB  From (values (1, 'H'), (4,'V'), (5,'W'), (6,'X'), (7,'Y'), (8,'Z')) as X(ColA, Colb)) as TableB
Where Tableb.ColA > TableA.Col1
) as TableC
```

The current results are:

[image]

The results I'd like to achieve is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that there are not enough identifiers binding the two tables together, and the where clause `Tableb.ColA > TableA.Col1` rings true for the first value on the second table and the first three values on the first table. I would suggest having direct relationship between the two tables, or a LEFT JOIN CLAUSE joined at their row numbers.

```
Select TableA.Col1, TableA.Col2, TableC.Colb

From
(Select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by x.Col1) AS 'ColNum', x.Col1, X.Col2  From (values(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D'), (5, 'E'), (6, 'F')) as X(Col1, Col2)) as TableA


LEFT JOIN
(Select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TableB.ColA) AS ColA, TableB.ColB
From (Select x.ColA, X.ColB  From (values(4,'V'), (5,'W'), (6,'X'), (7,'Y'), (8,'Z')) as X(ColA, Colb)) as TableB) AS TableC ON TableC.ColA = TableA.ColNum
```

Comment: I have edited the original question to make it clearer.
Value 1 2 and 3 in Col1 returns V as it's the first value in TableB that is greater than 3.
As V has been "used" in row 1, I want Row2 to return W and so on.

Comment: As per the answer by Horia, this doesn't work if data in TableC is not within the range that should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can number the rows in your `TableA` and `TableB` and `LEFT JOIN` on that:

```
WITH    TableA
    AS ( SELECT x.Col1 ,
                X.Col2 , 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY X.Col2) rw
        FROM    ( VALUES ( 1, 'A'), ( 2, 'B'), ( 3, 'C'), ( 4, 'D'), ( 5, 'E'), ( 6, 'F') ) AS X ( Col1, Col2 )
        ),
TableB
    AS ( SELECT x.ColA ,
                X.ColB , 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY X.ColB) rw
        FROM    ( VALUES ( 4, 'V'), ( 5, 'W'), ( 6, 'X'), ( 7, 'Y'), ( 8, 'Z') ) AS X ( ColA, Colb )
        )
SELECT  TableA.Col1 ,
        TableA.Col2 ,
        TableB.Colb
FROM    TableA
        LEFT JOIN TableB 
            ON TableA.rw = TableB.rw
```

This produces the result you need.

Comment: That works in the small example given, but it I have a number in TableB.ColA that is < TableA.Col1 then it doesn't work.

Comment: I have edited the example query in the main question to show an example of this (1, 'H') should not be selected anywhere as 1 is not > 2 but in your example H is returned